# Xamarin Forms Binding IEnumerable Localisation

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, localization, ienumerable

I have an app which I'm in the process of localising.  I'm using https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/LocalizationSample as a guide.  The App has a list of languages allowing the user to switch at any point.

Currently all of the translation's use binding so that when the language changes the values are updated.

My question is, what would be the best approach to localising ienumerables?  Should I use a  list of keys and translate them as required, or have multiple lists for each language?

I'm thinking something like the following:

- in the translation logic, check to keys that relate to lists
- if it's a list, loop through each item and translate it

Another idea was to create a dictionary of each support language and the translated ienumerable.  The key would be the language code, e.g. 'en-gb', then when the language changes I could rebind to that ienumerable in the dictionary.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how best to implement?

Comment: Are you talking about localizing IEnumerable<string> values ? or IEnumerable<T> where T is a class that contains 'string' properties to display ?

Comment: It's pretty much always IEnumerable<string> - if it were IEnumerable<object> then there would be a Display property of type String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you want to translate `IEnumerable<string>`...

How do you populate your Lists ? If you use resx files (for instance AppResources.resx, AppResources.en.resx), it should be done automatically.

In your ViewModel, init your list like this:

```
...
MyValues = new List<string>();
mMyValues.Add( AppResources.MyEnumValue1 );
mMyValues.Add( AppResources.MyEnumValue2 );
...
```

==> Calling  'AppResources.MyEnumValue2' will give you **the current culture** value for the key 'MyenumValue2'...

So there is no problem I think ?